# evaluate "main = return (getChar, getChar)"

Tags: haskell

I am  sorry that I am not good to speak english.

Let's see code below.

```
main = getChar
```

first, main will be evaluated, and it's value is "getChar", but compiler don't know "getChar" value, so compiler will evaluate "getChar" to calculate "getChar" value, and so , getChar will be executed.

Actually when i tested the code above. "getChar is executed.

Let's see code below.

```
main = return (getChar, getChar)
```

First, main evaluated, it's value is return (undefined, undefined) -> IO (undefined, undefined), so prelude will evaluate IO (undefined, undefined) to print the value. so one of two getChar will be evaluated.

but, when i tested the code above, none of two getChar was not evaluated . I don't understand why none of two getChar is evaluated.

Comment: By the way, where did you get the information that the result of main should get printed? This is not so. It just gets discarded anyway.

Comment: `return X` does not perform effects of `X`. For example, `main = return getChar` will do nothing.

Comment: Can anyone here provide an applicative-style version of that code that does what the OP wants?

Comment: @missingno: `(,) <$> getChar <*> getChar`

Answer (score 4):

You must actually execute your monadic actions then return the results of their execution.

```
func = do
    a <- getChar
    b <- getChar
    return  (a,b)
```

What you are currently doing is like the C statement:

```
void main(char &a, char &b)
{
    a = getchar;
    b = getchar;
}
```

as opposed to what you really want:

```
void main(char &a, char &b)
{
    a = getchar();
    b = getchar();
}
```

Comment: Thank you , Thomas. I know that i should use "do notation" to execute monadic value sequentially.

Comment: In that case I do not understand what your issue is.  If you could provide the type signature or behavior you desire vs what you are observing then that would help.

Comment: I want to know why none of two getChar is not evaluated.

Comment: Because you didn't evaluate it with either binds (`getChar >>= \x -> ...`) or do notation.

Comment: ok, thomas, sorry for my poor english. In the "main = getChar", getChar is evaluated and executed. why? I think that ">>=" operator is for "specifying order of evaluation - not for executing"

Comment: @user1286894: What you give to `main` is a _description_ of IO action. If you write `main = getChar`, you tell `main` to get one char. What happens if you write `return (getChar, getChar)`? `return` can be thought of as an action that does nothing and produces the value you specified. And here comes the problem: you're saying "do nothing and give me back `(getChar, getChar)`", which is then ignored (`main` has type `IO ()`). `>>=` is meant for _composing_ two actions together, it could mean something like "once you execute the first action, take its result and pass it to second action".

Comment: And the only action that is executed is `main`, which in turn can cause other actions to be executed - thanks to the composing operator (`>>=`). This allows you to treat `IO` actions as first class values. For example you can have a function that takes an `IO` action and returns a new one - and you are guaranteed nothing is executed unless it reaches `main`.

Answer (score 0):

> "I want to know why none of two getChar is not evaluated"

First, in english, like in logic or math or haskell, (not (not p)) == p, hence your question is:

> I want to know why both of the two getChars are evaluated.

Confusing, because I bet none of them is evaluated.

Your main function computes a value of IO a, and the value inside the IO with type a will then be evaluated. In your case, a is (IO Char, IO Char). Because Haskell is a non strict language, evaluating a tuple just means construct the tuple. This does not include evaluation of the tuple components. For example:

```
fst (42, 7 `quot` 0 :: Int)
```

will not abort with division by zero error.
Hence we have:

```
(getChar, getChar)
```

is a tuple with 2 unevaluated values.
But even if the values are evaluated, we have 2 values of type IO Char. Such a value can be seen as an action that, when executed in the IO monad, returns a Char.

Hence, not only are your tuple components not evaluated, they are not executed in the IO monad either.

To achieve this you could pass the tuple with the two actions to another action:

```
executeBoth (a,b) = do
    ra <- a
    rb <- b
    return (ra, rb)
```

Now, go, check the type of executeBoth and you'll probably see the point.

Comment: thanks a ton. sorry for my mistake. I modified that. It means "none of them is evaluated".

Comment: reading your answers, so now I know that "main = (undefined, undefined)" will be not evaluated.

Comment: but, I have a question. When haskell compiles "main = getChar", I think haskell evaluate it to "main = undefined" , so "getChar" will not be evaluated. but when i test the code, it was evaluated. can you explain that ?

Comment: @user1286894 - The (IO a) result of main will both be evaluated *and* executed. When you write return (getChar, getChar), the result is IO (IO Char, IO Char). The outer IO action is executed and yields a tuple. The components of the tuple are neither evaluated nor executed.